# Почему ответ функции 111

Tags: python-3.x

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему ответ третьего метода = 111?
То есть print (count) выдаёт ответ 111

```
def name (first, second = 1):
    name = first * second
    print (name)
name ('name', 9)

def say(message, times = 1):
    print(message * times)
say('Привет')
say('Мир', 5)

def retur(first, *second, **Third):
    count = first
    for seconds in second:
        count += seconds
    for third in Third:
        count += Third[third]
        #print (second, '\n', Third)
    return count        
print (retur (15, 13, 19, 21, check = 9, check_two = 15, check_three = 19))
```

Comment: а сколько должно быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `retur` прибавляет все аргументы следующим образом:

В `count` будет сумма, а для начала только первый аргумент функции (15):

```
count = first
```

В `second` будут все неименованные аргументы функции - 13, 19, 21 (потому-что `*` - [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments)):

```
for seconds in second:
    count += seconds
```

А в `Third` будут все именованные аргументы функции - 9, 15, 19 (потому-что `**`):

```
for third in Third:
    count += Third[third]
```

В итоге функция вернёт сумму всех аргументов - 111.

```
return count
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо!